# Rhinoscript MoveObject Python to C#

Tags: c#, python, transform, grasshopper, rhino3d

I'm converting a Python script to C# and I'm running into the occasional issue along the way. This time it's with relocating a point from one location to another. In the python script it's line two of the method that I don't know how to convert. I've reviewed the Rhino documentation but I'm still confused.

```
def move(self):
    self.trailPts.append(self.pos)
    self.pos = rs.PointCoordinates(rs.MoveObject(self.id, self.vec))
```

This is where I'm at so far:

```
Transform trans = new Transform(Transform.Translation(Vec));
Pos = PointID.Transform(Pos, trans, true);
```

But it's not correct. I'm getting an overload error for Transform on line 2. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Here is my C# constructor as well :

```
public Agent(Point3d pos, Vector3d vec, Point3d pointID, List<Point3d> listOfAgents, List<Point3d> navPoints, List<Circle> pipeProfiles)
        {
            Pos = pos;
            Vec = vec;
            PointID = pointID;
            ListOfAgents = listOfAgents;
            NavPoints = navPoints;
            PipeProfiles = pipeProfiles;

            TrailPoints.Add(new Point3d(Pos));
        }
```

And the original python constructor :

```
 def __init__(self, POS, VEC, POINTID, LISTOFAGENTS, NAVPOINTS, PIPEPROFILES):
        self.pos = POS
        self.vec = VEC
        self.id = POINTID
        self.list = LISTOFAGENTS
        self.nav = NAVPOINTS
        self.trailPts = []
        self.trailPts.append(self.pos)
        self.trailID = "empty"
        self.pipeProfiles = PIPEPROFILES
        print("made an agent")
```

Answer (score 0):

`MoveObject()` is a wrapper for `MoveObjects` where the first result value is returned rather than a list. Looking at the [RhinoScript implementation for `MoveObjects`](https://github.com/mcneel/rhinoscriptsyntax/blob/f81766f6799303530e3b3d36aff8985a633ffb6e/Scripts/rhinoscript/object.py#L718-L741) we see:

```
xf = Rhino.Geometry.Transform.Translation(translation)
rc = TransformObjects(object_ids, xf)
return rc
```

where `translation` is a `Vector3d` object.

Then looking at [`TransformObjects`](https://github.com/mcneel/rhinoscriptsyntax/blob/f81766f6799303530e3b3d36aff8985a633ffb6e/Scripts/rhinoscript/object.py#L1770-L1818)  the call comes down to

```
scriptcontext.doc.Objects.Transform(id, xf, True)
```

The [`PointCoordinates()` function](https://github.com/mcneel/rhinoscriptsyntax/blob/f81766f6799303530e3b3d36aff8985a633ffb6e/Scripts/rhinoscript/geometry.py#L713-L738) takes the GUID that `MoveObject()` returned and finds you the object again, then gives you the location for the geometry of that object (via [`coercegeometry()`](https://github.com/mcneel/rhinoscriptsyntax/blob/f81766f6799303530e3b3d36aff8985a633ffb6e/Scripts/rhinoscript/utility.py#L950-L965) and provided `.Geometry` is a [`Point` instance](https://developer.rhino3d.com/api/RhinoCommon/html/T_Rhino_Geometry_Point.htm)); skipping tests and functions to convert possible other acceptable types this comes down to:

```
scriptcontext.doc.Objects.Find(id).Geometry.Location
```

Translating these to RhinoCommon objects would be:

```
using Rhino.Geometry;
using System;

Transform xf = Transform.Translation(vec);
id = doc.Objects.Transform(id, xf, true);
Point pos = doc.Objects.Find(id).Geometry as Point
Point3d pos3d = pos.Location;
```

where `vec` is a `Rhino.Geometry.Vector3d` instance, and `id` an object reference.

Also see the [`Rhino.Geometry.Transform.Translation()` documentation](https://developer.rhino3d.com/api/RhinoCommon/html/M_Rhino_Geometry_Transform_Translation.htm), which include a C# example, and the [`ObjectTable.Transform` methods](https://developer.rhino3d.com/api/RhinoCommon/html/Overload_Rhino_DocObjects_Tables_ObjectTable_Transform.htm).

Note that the `Rhino.Geometry.Transform.Translation()` static method already returns a `Transform` instance, no need to use `new Transform()` here. And there is no `PointID` type; perhaps you were looking for [`Rhino.Geometry.Point3D`](https://developer.rhino3d.com/api/RhinoCommon/html/T_Rhino_Geometry_Point3d.htm)? The `Point3D.Transform()` method would operate on that point, however, not on an object with a given `id`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I still don't understand where my code is incorrect.

Comment: @greyBow: I have very little C# experience (literally, only from reading documentation when answering Stack Overflow questions), so take my reading with a grain of salt here. But why the `new Transform(...)` call when `Rhino.Geometry.Transform.Translation` already returns a `Transform` instance? And I could not find *any* information on `PointID`, so I'm not sure where that could have come from.

Comment: @greyBow: was that a confusion with other `Rhino.Geometry.Point*d` structures? (there's Point2d, Pointn3d, and Point4d). However, points can't be used to transform (move) an object, you need a vector for that.

Comment: PointID is actually a Point3d passing through my constructor

Comment: @greyBow: but the Python script doesn't have any such objects. There's only `self.pos`, `self.vec` and `self.id`, with `self.pos` being updated.

Comment: Just added my C# constructor and anf original python constructor. id is being passed through PointID which is a Point3d which is getting created via `coord = rs.PointCoordinates(ptObject)`

Comment: Right, so that’s `self.id` in the Python code and `id` in my translation.

Comment: So in your translation, what is doc.Objects ?

Comment: `doc` is the current document.

Comment: I get `doc doesn't exist in the current context` error

Comment: @greyBow: Then I don't think I can help any further, sorry. I don't have Rhino3d installed.